# What is the exact meaning of "English"? Why this language identified as "English"?

Tags: meaning, language-evolution

It struck me while searching for the meaning of the word *English*: what could be the meaning of the word "English", and why is this language called "English"?

Comment: You might like to start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_English_language

Comment: To phrase it more bluntly than @Barrie did: Voting to close as general reference.

Comment: @BarrieEngland Disappointingly, that Wiki entry doesn't seem to have a short one sentence etymology of the word *English,* I might have missed something, though.

Comment: [English](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=English&allowed_in_frame=0)

Comment: What Seems Obvious is Not Always Apparent. (Yumi Janairo Roth: http://www.yumijroth.com/What_Seems_Obvious_2.html)

Answer (score 1):

Look here for some some outline information on the etymology of the word *English*.

[**English**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=english&searchmode=term) (n.1)
"people or speech of England," O.E. *Englisc*, from *Engle* (pl.) "the Angles," the name of one of the Germanic groups that overran the island 5c., supposedly so-called because *Angul*, the land they inhabited on the Jutland coast, was shaped like a fish hook (see *[angle](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=angle&allowed_in_frame=0)* (n.)). The term was used from earliest times without distinction for all the Germanic invaders -- Angles, Saxon, Jutes (Bede's *gens Anglorum*) -- and applied to their group of related languages by Alfred the Great. After 1066, of the population of England (as distinguished from Normans and French), a distinction which lasted only about a generation. In pronunciation, "En-" has become "In-," but the older spelling has remained. Meaning "English language or literature as a subject at school" is from 1889. *Old English* is from early 13c.